# Laravel eager loading with constrains Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, database, eloquent, eager-loading

I have a problem with laravel eager loading (if it is an eager loading concern).

A have `products` table (`id`, `name`, `photo`, `slug`) and `attributes` table (`id`, `product_id`, `price`, `sale_price`, `amount`, `size`).

One product could have several attributes (in my case, it is clothes, 1 product can have multiple sizes due to different amounts in stock, etc.).

I want to paginate products and show the price and sale price if one exists. So I'm trying to eager load (with constraints) the attribute model with `sale_price` and `amount` > 0 if one exists and one with no `sale_price` and `amount` > 0. I want to get 1 (or two if `sale_price` exists) models, but I seem to miss something important.

##### Attribute class

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class Attribute extends Pivot
{
    use HasFactory;

    public $incrementing = true;
    
    protected $table = 'attributes';
    
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }
    
    public function size()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Size::class);
    }
    
    public function scopeOnSale(Builder $query): void
    {
        $query->whereNotNull('sale_price');
    }
    
    public function scopeNotOnSale(Builder $query): void
    {
        $query->whereNull('sale_price');
    }
    
    public function scopeInStock(Builder $query): void
    {
        $query->where('amount', '!=', 0);
    }
}
```

##### Product class

```php
namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Category;
use App\Models\Size;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }

    public function attributes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Attribute::class);
    }

    public function scopeWithAttributes(Builder $query): void
    {
        $query->with(['attributes' => function ($query) {
            $query->where(function ($query) {
                $query->inStock()->onSale();
            })
            ->orWhere(fn ($query) => $query->inStock());
        }]);
    }

    public function scopeAmountInStock(Builder $query): void
    {
        $query->withSum('attributes as available_in_stock', 'amount');
    }

    public function scopeFilter(Builder $query): void
    {
        $query->orderByRaw(
            '(CASE WHEN available_in_stock != 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC'
        );
    }
}
```

##### Render function (using LiveWire in my project)

```php
public function render()
{
    return view(
        'livewire.product.show-products',
        [
            'products' => $this->category
                ? Product::whereBelongsTo($this->category)
                    ->with('category')
                    ->withAttributes()
                    ->amountInStock()
                    ->filter()
                    ->paginate(9)
                    ->onEachSide(0)
                : Product::with('category')
                    ->withAttributes()
                    ->amountInStock()
                    ->filter()
                    ->paginate(9)
                    ->onEachSide(0)
        ]
    )->layout('components.layout');
}
```

`scopeWithAttributes` from the `Product` class should do the work, but I don't know how to make it perform proper db request.

As for the request for the `Attributes` table, I get something like this (according to the clockwork package):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `attributes`
WHERE `attributes`.`product_id` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11)
    AND (
        `amount` != 0
        AND `sale_price` IS NOT NULL
    )
    OR (`amount` != 0)
```

Please, help me to figure out how I can get only 1 (or 2) requests to the attributes table to get only the needed attribute record.